# Django 2.2 can't connect to ElastiCache Redis on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, redis, memcached

I have Django 2.2 app running on AWS that is working correctly with `Memcached` on AWS ElastiCache but for some reason, it will not connect to a Redis server on AWS ElastiCache.

I have added the permissions to my security groups but no luck and the http request just hangs until it will timeout.

Even though a similar behavior is usually related with security groups, I feel that I may be missing some Redis specific packages in my `.requirements` or `Yum` packages in `.ebextensions` as everything is working correctly locally, and with `Memcached` server on AWS as well.

Perhaps, do I have to somehow start/enable the Redis server to start accepting connections?

Here is what I have.

**settings.py**

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': 'redis://myendpoint.cache.amazonaws.com:6379',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
    }
}
```

}

**.ebextensions**

```
packages:
    yum:
        python36-devel: []
        mysql-devel: []
        libmemcached-devel: []
        gcc: []
        gcc-c++: []
        libffi-devel: []

option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "api.settings"
```

**requirements.txt**

```
blessed==1.15.0
botocore==1.12.137
cached-property==1.5.1
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
django-redis==4.10.0
Django==2.2.1
djangorestframework==3.9.2
docutils==0.14
future==0.16.0
future==0.16.0
idna==2.7
jmespath==0.9.4
jsonschema==2.6.0
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
pathspec==0.5.9
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-memcached==1.59
pytz==2019.1
PyYAML==3.13
redis==3.2.1
requests==2.20.1
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
texttable==0.9.1
urllib3==1.24.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.56.0
```

Comment: what's the exact error you're getting? and are the redis instance and your ec2 instance sharing the same security group?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, same security group. I already tried to create a separate SG just for the Redis but no luck and same results. I'm not sure how to view these type of Redis timeout errors but the page is stuck at loading for 5min and then it will finally load the page. Seems like there is a default timeout 300 and when what expires, the app will grab the results from the RDS server. Any suggestions how to check the Redis server connection? Again, the same Memcached ElastiCache is working OK.

Comment: ssh into your Django machine, start a shell with manage.py shell —settings=path.to.settings and directly try writing/reading to the cache. That should show you the error.

Comment: Also you don’t have logs that show the error?

Comment: @dirkgroten Not sure if I'm reviewing the errors correctly, but the logs are not showing any error specific to to this timeout. Would that be under var/log/httpd/error_log? The only suspicious is `mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled`.  Also when you say write directly to the cache, what are the commands for that?

Comment: First I’d look at your Django logs. If you don’t have them then that’s the first thing you need to do: enable logging of all Django errors to file. Then at syslog.

Comment: @dirkgroten Will do, Thanks! Once enabled, where can I view the logs through the AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm still having hard time getting the Django logs going, but when I ssh to the instance and try `redis-cli -h my-cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379`
Could not connect to Redis at my-cache.amazonaws.com:6379:6379: Name or service not known. Any suggestions?

Comment: well that would explain the problem, so you're on the right track. I would again check the security group settings of your ElastiCache instance. It must accept incoming tcp connections on port 6379 with the source set to the sg of your ec2 instance and in the same vpc as your ec2 instance. Also why does the error duplicate the port?

Comment: Getting closer: I have attached second SG to the ElastiBeanstalk instance and now I'm getting timeout. `redis-cli -h cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 ping
Could not connect to Redis at cache.amazonaws.com:6379: Connection timed out` . Any suggestions for the time-out error?

Comment: seems like it can now find it because it's in the same vpc/subnet, but still your redis instance isn't allowing incoming connections from that source or on that port. or your instance's sg isn't allowing outgoing connections using that port (that would be strange, but check to be sure)? if you can't figure it out, ask for help to the support team.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks again for your time and your help. With your suggestions, I was able to get it going. It turned out that for some reason, the test instance was not part a VPC and while it had a SG that was part of a VPC and had the correct ports opened it did not work. I have created a new environment inside the correct VPC and voila! If you would create an official answer, I would love to mark it as correct answer. Once again, you time is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All supported versions of django-redis depends on redis-py >= 2.10.0

[django-redis documentation](https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_requirements)

Comment: I have added that to my requirements.txt and I'm getting `ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.` Any suggestions?